# Can someone explain this with example?(Abstract Data Type)

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures, linked-list, abstract-data-type

So i was reading about data structures and then I got to Abstract Data Type.
And I want to clear few things
Firstly here's what I understood
Abstract Data Type:It's basically programming everything for users and allowing them just to use it as features without them actually knowing how it works.
Please correct if I understood this wrongly
Now the doubt I really can't understand
Here's the text from the book where they give the student example and say that If I want to add a extra field to student's info then it's better to use linked list but I don't seem to get how?

**"In the real world, programs evolve as a result of new requirements or constraints, so a modification  to a program commonly requires a change in one or more of its data structures. For example, if  you want to add a new field to a student’s record to keep track of more information about each  student, then it will be better to replace an array with a linked structure to improve the program’s  efficiency. In such a scenario, rewriting every procedure that uses the changed structure is not  desirable. Therefore, a better alternative is to separate the use of a data structure from the details  of its implementation. This is the principle underlying the use of abstract data types.""**

It would be great if anyone can help

Comment: If the array is an array of student records, the book does not appear to be correct. Adding a new field to the record has nothing to do with whether the records are managed with an array or a linked list. If the array the book is talking about is the student record, such as an array of grades, and you want the ability to expand a student’s record by adding more grades, then it might make some sense to use a linked list for each record. But it is not clear. In any case, this might not be a good book. I would not worry about this point and would move on.

Comment: Thanks for answering and actually it's from one of the reference books that we are suggested for our curriculum and many people recommended it. It might be a error, Nevertheless it would be great if you can suggest any resources for data structures and algorithms.

Comment: It looks like they tried very hard to come up with an example where the implementation of a data structure changes and the example is not so great after all. The important thing here is dealing with the consequences of "you suddenly decide to replace the array with a linked list". Why exactly you made that decision is not relevant to this explanation.

Comment: @Stef  Actually they tried to explain how using an abstract data type is useful because if you keep things abstract you can change it and then concluding it as the principle for using abstract data types...